# How to find invariant subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Good morning, i don't understand too good the theory about invariant subspaces.

**My definition:** Let $V$ a $\mathbb{K}-$vector space, $W$ a subspace of $V$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$. If $T(W)\subset W$ we say W is $T-$invariant

I try to make some examples, for example this:

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T(x,y,z)=(x-2y+z,0,x+y+z)$

I know $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ are the trivial invariant subspaces, but how can i find the non trivial subspaces? Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about eigenspaces? Also, your example $T$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$. You might have trouble with that.

Comment: Pardon me, but your $T(x,y,z)$ lies in $\mathbf R^2$.

Comment: Sorry @Bernard i fix the exercise, thanks!!!

Comment: @DavidBowman thanks i fix the exercise thanks!

Comment: Think about projection onto a nontrivial subspace $W$. Then $T$ will be the identity on $W$. Think about the earth's rotation about its axis. The equatorial plane is invariant.

Comment: In your example then, the line spanned by $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ (provided I didn't miscompute it) is invariant under $T$. Do you see why? Are there others?

Comment: No i don't see why @DavidBowman...

Comment: Try computing the eigenvectors of $T$. The spans of eigenvectors are invariant subspaces because if $Tv = \lambda v$ then $T(cv) = cTv = c\lambda v = (c\lambda)v \in span(v)$.

Comment: @DavidBowman Yes, now i see why $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is invariant under $T$, thx.

Comment: @DavidBowman i found other invariant subspace, $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ one question 
How can I be sure that they are all invariant subspaces?